Retry on task failure only on certain conditions
I get an intermittent failure in my pipeline that causes me to have to restart jobs occasionally.  The output string as a result of this failure is predictable.  Let's say it's, "The build has failed."  I want to retry the job automatically using 'retryCountOnTaskFailure:' only on the condition that the string is present in the output of the original task.  This would prevent the job from retrying if it was a more legitimate failure.  How do I condition this?
This is using Azure Devops and *.yaml scripts. The job looks something like:
job: my_job
steps:
  - powershell: |
      cmake .
    retryCountOnTaskFailure: 1

I've added retryCountOnTaskFailure as is shown in the DevOps docs but this will always retry the job regardless of what type of failure occurs.

As of now, I am afraid that there is no functionality out-of-the-box to automatically rerun an agent job, not to mention how to rerun the job on certain conditions. As far as I tested, we could encounter the error below when attempting to rerun the current build during the build.

With those being said, you may try the workaround to conditionally rerun a stage instead of a build/job with the help of this API.

When the PredictFailure PowerShell task in my_job of stage A fails with a predictable error, it outputs a variable $(PredictFailure.message) with the value of TheBuildHasFailed.
The downstream agentless job trigger_stageB of stage A will evaluate the status of my_job and if the value of the output variable dependencies.my_job.outputs['PredictFailure.message'] equals TheBuildHasFailed; once evaluations are passed, it will then Invoke REST API to trigger stage B of the current build.
Stage B will rerun only the failed jobs in stage A after a timespan of manual validation. You can reject the rerun request within in that timespan.

Here is my sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
variables:
  OrgName: ${{ split(variables['System.CollectionUri'], '/')[3] }} # Extract organization name from $(System.CollectionUri) - https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: my_job
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "When the step is predictable to fail with the failure TheBuildHasFailed, then output"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=message;isoutput=true]TheBuildHasFailed"
        exit 1
      name: PredictFailure
    - powershell: |
        echo $(PredictFailure.message)
      displayName: Check output
      condition: always()

  - job: trigger_stageB
    dependsOn: my_job
    condition: and(
        failed(),
        eq(dependencies.my_job.outputs['PredictFailure.message'], 'TheBuildHasFailed')
      )
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
        serviceConnection: 'AzureDevOpsServices'
        method: 'PATCH'
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",  
            "Authorization": "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
          }
        body: |
          {
            "state":2,
            "forceRetryAllJobs":true,
            "retryDependencies":true
          }
        urlSuffix: '$(OrgName)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/stages/B?api-version=7.1'
        waitForCompletion: 'false'

- stage: B
  trigger: manual
  pool: server
  jobs:
  - job: rerun_stageA
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@1
      inputs:
        onTimeout: 'resume'
      timeoutInMinutes: 1 # Wait for 1 minute before rerun; the rerun request can be rejected manualy within the timespan;
    - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
        serviceConnection: 'AzureDevOpsServices'
        method: 'PATCH'
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",  
            "Authorization": "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
          }
        body: |
          {
            "state": 1,
            "forceRetryAllJobs": "false",
            "retryDependencies": "true"
          }
        urlSuffix: '/$(OrgName)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/stages/A?api-version=7.1'
        waitForCompletion: 'false'


